# Create a Deployment Package to folder TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I currently have Team City set up on a server that does:

1) Build the Project

2) Run unit tests

3) Publish the project through IIS if successful

I want to add another step so that a .zip file is produced consisting of what was deployed to a directory on the server running team city. I am to understand that this is possible through artefacts but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked to give me the publish output.

I've tried options such as "** => C:\TC\Test.zip" but that includes the actual code implementation files.

Is there a way in which to publish a zip containing the publish result?

I've been trying this for hours without luck so far so hopefully I can get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to zip all files relative to the root of the build:

```
**/* => artifacts.zip
```

To zip all files relative to a folder named publish:

```
publish/**/* => artifacts.zip
```

If your published files are not included in the zip, they may have been published to someplace outside of the root of the build.